# Determining the required threshold for a filter

Tags: noise

Tinkering with a Freetronics microphone board and an Arduino, I found that the microphone board is quite poor at rejecting noise on its power rail.

SPL (sound pressure level) reported widely ranging values in a quiet room, and after initial confusion I sensed a pattern. If I had an oscilloscope this would probably be a very short tale but I don't, so instead I programmed the Arduino to take 300 samples as fast as it could, wrote them to the serial console and copied them to excel, where graphing them produced this:

[image: SPL over time]

600 samples just has more of the second wave, regular as clockwork. Indeed, it probably *is* a clock pulse, coming out of the USB port I use to listen to the Arduino serial comms.

The cure, I think, is a passive low-pass filter. But what frequency? Unfortunately I don't know how long a call takes to analogRead on an Arduino Nano with an Atmel 328P. If anyone happens to know that, I can compute the interval and the frequency for the pulse.

Otherwise, the question is (take your pick)

- How to determine this *without* a scope?
- What's a good cheap scope? (what's cheap for a scope?)
- Are those cheap Chinese scopes that require a computer worth having?

Another program to count crests (slope change from pos to neg) against the Arduino clock reveals it's a fairly steady 700Hz.

---

Epilogue

The documentation for the Nano says it will prefer the power supply with the highest voltage so I tried putting 7V into V<sub>IN</sub> in the hope that the internal linear regulator would clip the ripple. Victory! Better yet a little experimentation reveals that it actually only needs 6V. Ripples start to appear at 5V8. At 5V9 they vanish plus another 0.1V to seal the deal.

Comment: Is it this one? https://www.freetronics.com.au/products/microphone-sound-input-module You are sampling the SPL output, right?

Comment: Yes, that exact unit, and yes I just checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to determine this without a scope?

The [schematic](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0045/8932/files/MIC_MicrophoneSoundModule.pdf?100735) of your microphone module reveals that the 'SPL' channel is actually just a comparator that triggers when the instantaneous sound level exceeds a threshold (converting the audio waveform into 'square' pulses), followed by an RC low pass filter. This explains the shape of the waveform, and gives us a way to estimate the sampling rate and pulse frequency.

The RC low pass filter consists of a 1.2 kΩ resistor and 2.2 μF capacitor, which has a [time constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant) of 2.64 ms. The exponential discharge curve should drop to 36.8% in 1 time constant. Taking the first pulse as an example, it drops from ~790 to 291 in ~10 sample times. Therefore each sample took ~2.64 / 10 = 0.264 ms, which equates to ~3800 samples per second.

Another way to estimate the sampling frequency would be to increase the number of samples until the total time taken is long enough to measure by hand. So wrap your sampling code in an outer loop that repeats 1000 times, and it should take ~79 seconds to complete.

Once you have the sampling rate, determining the pulse frequency is simply a matter of measuring the time between pulses and inverting that period to get the frequency. Your low pass filter will probably need a much lower cutoff frequency to reduce noise to an acceptable level.

The microphone is powered via a 2.2 kΩ resistor (R2) connected directly to VCC. This may be where the noise is getting into the circuit.

> What's a good cheap scope? (what's cheap for a scope?)

For working with audio or low speed digital a single channel scope with 5 MHz bandwidth might be sufficient, but 20 MHz and 2 channels is the minimum for general purpose use. Analog scopes generally have greater fidelity and are easier to use. However they are bulky and the cheap ones do not have the advanced features of good digital scopes.

Expect to pay several hundred dollars for a 'good' cheap scope.

If you can't afford that much then a USB based scope such as the Hantek 6022BE [might work for you](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/hantek-6022be-will-it-work-for-me/).

At the bottom end are 'toy' scopes with very low bandwidth that use an MCU and small LCD display. These sell for ~$30 on eBay as a kit. They are almost useless.

Comment: The Hantek 6022BE is actually one of the units I've been looking at.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would do better to fix the noise at its source rather than trying to remove its effects from the output.

You are using an Arduino, so you've got 5V available somewhere.  Take that 5V and put it through a low drop out 3.3V linear regulator.

Your module will work at that voltage (the documents say it will work down to 2.7V.)

The regulator will cleanup the noise going into the module, and you won't have to try to clean up the output of the module.

---

As to measuring the frequency of the interference, you can use the sound card of a PC as a makeshift oscilloscope and (audio) spectrum analyzer.  There's free software available, and schematics available to make adapters that will (to some extent) protect your computer.

I use a 50 year old analog oscilloscope for most things, and sometimes my PC as an audio spectrum analyser.

Comment: It's a shame I can only accept one of these answers. This is what I get for mashing several questions together, I suppose. Using a LReg is a possibility I've been entertaining. The power pollution actually doesn't matter in production because I'm detecting engine run-state; picking up engine noise it doesn't matter whether the noise is electrical or audio. But on the bench while debugging, the noise from my computer is a jolly nuisance.